# Getting wrong time in Date while using Spring Rest Service

Tags: java, spring, datetime, jackson, java.util.date

This is my pojo class

```
public class TeTripCarDtl implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7601044160087552575L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "CAR_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long carId;

    @Column(name = "TRIP_ID")
    private long tripId;

    @Column(name = "VEHICLE_TYPE")
    private String vehicleType;

    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss", shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "PICKUP_DATE_TIME")
    private Date pickUpDateTime;// Here I am getting wrong time value

    @Temporal(value = TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss", shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING)
    @Column(name = "RETURN_DATE_TIME")
    private Date returnDateTime;// Here I am getting wrong time value

    @Column(name = "PICK_UP_LOCATION")
    private String pickUpLocation;

    @Column(name = "DROP_OFF_LOCATION")
    private String dropOffLocation;

    @Column(name = "CONFIRMED_SPECIAL_EQUIP")
    private String confirmedSpecialEquip;

    @Column(name = "LAST_UPDATED_BY")
    private String lastUpdatedBy;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "LAST_UPDATED_ON")
    private Date lastUpdatedOn;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "BOOKING_DATE")
    private Date bookingDate;

    @Column(name = "STATUS")
    private String status;

    public long getCarId() {
        return carId;
    }

    public void setCarId(long carId) {
        this.carId = carId;
    }

    public long getTripId() {
        return tripId;
    }

    public void setTripId(long tripId) {
        this.tripId = tripId;
    }

    public String getVehicleType() {
        return vehicleType;
    }

    public void setVehicleType(String vehicleType) {
        this.vehicleType = vehicleType;
    }

    public Date getPickUpDateTime() {
        return pickUpDateTime;
    }

    public void setPickUpDateTime(Date pickUpDateTime) {
        this.pickUpDateTime = pickUpDateTime;
    }

    public Date getReturnDateTime() {
        return returnDateTime;
    }

    public void setReturnDateTime(Date returnDateTime) {
        this.returnDateTime = returnDateTime;
    }

    public String getPickUpLocation() {
        return pickUpLocation;
    }

    public void setPickUpLocation(String pickUpLocation) {
        this.pickUpLocation = pickUpLocation;
    }

    public String getDropOffLocation() {
        return dropOffLocation;
    }

    public void setDropOffLocation(String dropOffLocation) {
        this.dropOffLocation = dropOffLocation;
    }

    public String getConfirmedSpecialEquip() {
        return confirmedSpecialEquip;
    }

    public void setConfirmedSpecialEquip(String confirmedSpecialEquip) {
        this.confirmedSpecialEquip = confirmedSpecialEquip;
    }

    public String getLastUpdatedBy() {
        return lastUpdatedBy;
    }

    public void setLastUpdatedBy(String lastUpdatedBy) {
        this.lastUpdatedBy = lastUpdatedBy;
    }

    public Date getLastUpdatedOn() {
        return lastUpdatedOn;
    }

    public void setLastUpdatedOn(Date lastUpdatedOn) {
        this.lastUpdatedOn = lastUpdatedOn;
    }

    public Date getBookingDate() {
        return bookingDate;
    }

    public void setBookingDate(Date bookingDate) {
        this.bookingDate = bookingDate;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "TeTripCarDtl [carId=" + carId + ", tripId=" + tripId + ", vehicleType=" + vehicleType
                + ", pickUpDateTime=" + pickUpDateTime + ", returnDateTime=" + returnDateTime + ", pickUpLocation="
                + pickUpLocation + ", dropOffLocation=" + dropOffLocation + ", confirmedSpecialEquip="
                + confirmedSpecialEquip + ", lastUpdatedBy=" + lastUpdatedBy + ", lastUpdatedOn=" + lastUpdatedOn
                + ", bookingDate=" + bookingDate + ", status=" + status + "]";
    }

}
```

Input json

```
    {"vehicleType":"ECAR","pickUpDateTime":"2017-06-10T07:30:04", "returnDateTime":"2017-06-10T07:30:04","pickUpLocation":"PNQ","dropOffLocation":"BOM","confirmedSpecialEquip":"HCL,TCS,INFO","status":"BOOKED"}
```

Spring Restcontroller class

```
@RestController
public class DateControllerTest {

    @RequestMapping(value="date_test", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String reciveData(@RequestBody TeTripCarDtl teTripCarDtl){
        System.out.println("PickUpDateAndTime:"+teTripCarDtl.getPickUpDateTime()+","
                + "ReturnDateAndTime:"+teTripCarDtl.getReturnDateTime());
        return "recived";
    }
}
```

I am printing date values in console it it is printing like this .Here I am getting time is wrong, I suppose to get time **07:30:04** but I am getting **13:00:04** except this everything is fine

```
    PickUpDateAndTime:Sat Jun 10 13:00:04 IST 2017,ReturnDateAndTime:Sat Jun 10 13:00:04 IST 2017
```

Please help me with this.

Comment: This seem like a timezone problem

Comment: But I am not specifying time zone anywhere in my code @DanielHigueras

Comment: That might be the problem: maybe you need to specify time zone.

Comment: As an aside, if you can, drop your use of the long outdated `Date` class and use for example `LocalDateTime` instead (I really think you should use `Instant`, but the string in your JSON matches a `LocalDateTime`).

Comment: I can't change Date to LocalDateTime because This application already implemented by my  team i am here to fix this issue  If I change this Date data type it will effect whole project @OleV.V.

Comment: @Srinu Please accept the answer if it has fixed your issue.

Comment: Easy, @SangamBelose, please. It is generally accepted to wait a couple of days before accepting an answer in case some more helpful info rolls in, since questions with an accepted answer get less attention. I agree of course in encouraging the asker to accept an answer eventually.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Jackson `@JsonFormat` annotation has a specific `timezone` attribute. If you specify the timezone you wish to use, you can fix this issue.

Example:

```
@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss", timezone = "Europe/Madrid")
```

Reference: http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.1.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonFormat.html

Answer (score 3):

The @JsonFormat annotations have timeZone issues. Please check the link for more details on issue.[jackson-data-bind issue](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/1266) Overriding the timezone in ObjectMapper didnt worked either. I have solved the problem by implementing custom Date Deserializer as below:

```
            @Component
            public class CustomDateDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<Date> {

                /**
                * 
                */
                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
                private SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"); // specify your specific timezone

                public CustomDateDeserializer() {
                this(null);
                }

                public CustomDateDeserializer(Class<?> vc) {
                super(vc);
                }

                @Override
                public Date deserialize(JsonParser jsonparser, DeserializationContext context)
                    throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
                String date = jsonparser.getText();
                try {
                    return formatter.parse(date);
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
                }
            }
```

and then apply the deserializer on setter method of your bean properties.

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = CustomDateDeserializer.class)
public void setReturnDateTime(Date returnDateTime) {
this.returnDateTime = returnDateTime;
}
```

similarly you can implement your custom serializer for vice versa operation.

Comment: @Srinu Please accept the answer if it is working for you.

Comment: Accepted your  answer .

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem before, it's a time zone problem, so I convert my date to string before sending, you can use this function to convert date to string :

```
public static String dateFormatString(Date date, String pattern) {
    if (date != null) {
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
        return formatter.format(date);
    }
    return null;
}
```

for the pattern you can use : yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss

Comment: Thanks for Answering. I am not bother about date format All I need is corect time value.

Answer (score 0):

It is a time zone issue. When you don't specify a timezone jackson consider that date is in UTC time and convert it to your default locale which is IST. As you can see **07:30:04 UTC** is equivalent to **13:00:04 IST**.

You can specify timezone in input json like this `"pickUpDateTime":"2017-06-10T07:30:04.000+05:30"` hence IST=UTC+5:30

Comment: You're Right But  I can't change json format because This application already implemented by some one I am here to fix this issue